# awk, save lines with the same value of a specific column

Tags: awk

I want to compare with AWK the values in column 7 between lines and save the lines in a file with the same value of the column 7. Then when the value change to save it in a new file ...

```
chr18   57650444    57650444    0   3.5 ST  mW1 chr18   57646426    57803315    
chr18   57668180    57668180    0   2.4 ST  mW1 chr18   57646426    57803315
chr18   57668180    57668180    0   2.4 ST  mW2 chr18   57646426    57803315
chr18   57650444    57650444    0   3.5 ST  mW1 chr18   57646426    57803315    
chr18   57650444    57650444    0   3.5 ST  mE3 chr18   57646426    57803315
```

I have to use isolate the column 7, like `awk '{print $7}'` and at the same time read the line `NR` and `NR-1`, finally compare the values of the 7th column between the first and second column and use "if", `awk '{if (NR-1 == NR) print NR}' inputfile >> "value_column_7".txt`
... I think something like this ...

What I want

```
filename: mW1.txt
    chr18   57650444    57650444    0   3.5 ST  mW1 chr18   57646426    57803315    
    chr18   57668180    57668180    0   2.4 ST  mW1 chr18   57646426    57803315
    chr18   57650444    57650444    0   3.5 ST  mW1 chr18   57646426    57803315    

filename: mW2.txt
    chr18   57668180    57668180    0   2.4 ST  mW2 chr18   57646426    57803315

filename: mE3.txt
    chr18   57650444    57650444    0   3.5 ST  mE3 chr18   57646426    57803315
```

Could you help me how to combine them?
Thanks

Comment: Could you please post sample expected output in your question and let us know then?

Comment: Edited, thanks! I changed also the example

Comment: Why do you have to compare anything? Just write the lines to appropriate file defined by `$7`, basically `{print > $7 ".txt"}` In case you start running out of fds, apply `close()`.

Comment: I am not sure about column numbering: Column 7 is mW1, mE3. Quite different than 57646426 57803315. Moreover, there aren't two lines in your data where the last column is identical to the last column -1. Please have a look and edit your question

Comment: James Brown is perfect your code !!! I made everything too much complicate ! Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to write to a file defined by `$7`:

```
$ awk '{
    file=$7 ".txt"       # name the file
    print >> file        # append to file
}' file
```

If you start running out of fds, or file descriptors, you need to start worrying about `close()`ing files:

```
$ awk '{
    if($7!=p) {          # if $7 as changed since previous record
        close(file)      # close the previous file
        file=$7 ".txt"   # name a new file based on $7
    }
    print >> file        # append to file in case of recurring $7
    p=$7                 # remember $7 for next record
}' file
```